# Configure Fiddler to capture from bridged network or specific network adapter

Tags: tv, wireshark, fiddler

Is it possible to configure Fiddler to capture from a bridged network or specific network adapter?

I have a TV plugged into my PC network card. Wireshark sees all packets to and from the TV but Fiddler sees nothing from the TV. Though it captures from the PC browser just fine.

Comment: @techie007 Nope, definitely not a duplicate. My question is "Is it possible to configure Fiddler to capture from a bridged network or specific network adapter?"

Comment: I would be surprised if Fiddler had this capability, but I will stay tuned here to see if anything is suggested.  Till then, why is it you can't see what is going on with WireShark?  Just filter for the http packets from the appropriate IP I think.

Comment: @ElipticalView Wireshark is great but I like Fiddlers features for what I'm working on.